# Find Current Location using Service on Android studio in java

Tags: java, android-studio, service, background-service, currentlocation

I want to get the current location and show it on my maps activity, but I have to move the part of the code that I use to find the current location to a background service which will start when i click the button start and nothing will work from what I have tried. This is the code I used before to find the current location:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

private LocationManager manager;

private LocationListener listener;

private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 3;

private MyService myService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
   

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.GoogleMap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            if(mMap!=null) {
                LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));

            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

    };
    getLocation();

    //initialize start and cancel button
    findViewById(R.id.startButton).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        //startService(intent);
       

    });

    findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setOnClickListener(view -> {
       
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        //stopService(serviceIntent);

        //return back to main activity
        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainActivity);
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode==LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        int count =0;
        for(String permission: permissions) {
            if(permission==android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION){
                if(grantResults[count]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    getLocation();
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}



private void getLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 50, listener);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location permission is denied, please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    getLocation();     
     
}
```

Comment: Hello. "Here's what worked but what I currently have (which I'm not showing) doesn't work. Please help." is not a good question. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with useful details people can use to help you.